# How to get Jenkins to show skipped tests

Tags: selenium, junit, jenkins

I found this Jenkins graph:

https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/TAP+Plugin#TAPPlugin-JenkinsJUnitcompatiblereportsandgraphs

It clearly shows red, blue, and yellow sections, yellow being "skipped" tests. I have defined a few "Ignore" tags in my tests but these do not show up as yellow in Jenkins. I am running JUnit Selenium test.

How do I get Jenkins to display skipped tests as a separate line?

Answer (score 0):

In [this post](http://jenkins.361315.n4.nabble.com/Is-it-possible-to-show-Ignore-JUnit-tests-td1565288.html#a1566166) to the mailing list:

> It works in the m2 job type so Hudson does support this.
>
> You need to drill down a fair way in m2 job to find the actual skipped test but the bar colour is red=failed blue=passed yellow=skipped.

So this won't work in Ant builds, only Maven ones. However,
a related bug ([#43969](https://issues.apache.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=43969)) was fixed in Ant 1.9.0, [released on 2013-03-07](http://ant.apache.org/antnews.html), so upgrading to that version of Ant may improve results.

Answer (score 0):

That is for test harness' written with TAP (Test Any Protocol). If you are using PERL as you choice of language you can set up tests with `SKIP` conditions in the `TEST::More` module.
For more info look at [this](http://perldoc.perl.org/Test/More.html) (look at line 26 in the sample code).

Comment: I see. We use JUnit with Java

Comment: So well there you go thats your answer. The module in question is for displaying TAP results.